# Nuxt Vitest page unit testing with SSR: false

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, nuxt.js, single-page-application, vitest

I am trying to performed End to End testing on my index.vue page according to the [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/testing#apis). My project requires that SSR is false but, when disabled, my Vitest unit tests fail.

This is my index.nuxt.test.js file:

```
import { describe, expect, it } from 'vitest'
import { setup, $fetch } from '@nuxt/test-utils'

describe('The page starts up', async () => {
  await setup({
    rootDir: '../',
    server: true
  })

  it('contains "welcome to the homepage"', async () => {
    expect(await $fetch('/')).toMatch('homepage')
  })
})
```

Logging the fetch results shows that the fetched HTML in SPA mode is a static page that I assume is hydrated later, so Vitest cannot match the word "homepage" in it. How can I unit test the fully hydrated page?

I have tried using `mountSuspended` from the docs, but now it seems to error because of the I18n module I'm using with Nuxt

```
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Unhandled Rejection ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
SyntaxError: Need to install with `app.use` function
 ❯ Module.createCompileError node_modules/@intlify/message-compiler/dist/message-compiler.mjs:78:19
     76|         : code;
     77|     const error = new SyntaxError(String(msg));
     78|     error.code = code;
       |                   ^
     79|     if (loc) {
     80|         error.location = loc;
 ❯ createI18nError node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.mjs:105:34
 ❯ Module.useI18n node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.mjs:2316:15
 ❯ setup pages/index.vue:18:39
 ❯ wrappedSetup node_modules/@nuxt/test-utils/dist/runtime-utils/index.mjs:93:26
 ❯ clonedComponent.setup node_modules/@nuxt/test-utils/dist/runtime-utils/index.mjs:141:48
 ❯ callWithErrorHandling node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:193:18
 ❯ setupStatefulComponent node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7553:25
 ❯ setupComponent node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7514:36
 ❯ mountComponent node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5843:7
```